# Is there a way to determine which hardware is throwing excessive interrupts

Tags: interrupts

I am trying to get an old P.C. working so that I can use its floppy drive to read some old diskettes.  It boots from an Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS DVD but it has a really bad, "cursor drag," as I call it.  When I type a command in a terminal window, it takes a few seconds for each, successive character in the command to be displayed on the screen.  The response is painfully slow.  I assume that this is being caused by some hardware component failing and throwing excessive interrupts against the system.  The CPU is at 100%.
Hence my question: is there a way to determine which hardware is throwing the interrupts.
I realize this is not an operating system question, but maybe someone here knows of a way.

Comment: Have a look at the `/var/log/kern.log` to see which...

Comment: Could be a failing piece of hardware, or something rather obvious, like an old graphics card that can't handle Unity.

Comment: **Off-topic [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/287151) comment:** to clone your floppy disks, you can try to use [another lightweight distribution along with `ddrescue`](https://github.com/crushedice2000/olddrescue) or even with some modern over-engineered [specialized controller](https://www.kryoflux.com).

Comment: Also, you can buy a cheap USB floppy disk drive to some Chinese on-line sellers or even, if you're lucky,  in you local computer store.

Comment: Related to your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25203/how-can-i-know-which-irq-is-responsible-of-high-cpu-usage